# How do I use WP_Query to get a range of posts with custom fields that have numbers with letters in them?

Tags: posts, wp-query

### What I'm trying to do

I am using `WP_Query()` to get posts based on their range for example:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'parameters',
            'value' => 'width',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'value',
            'value' => array( '22mm', '55mm' ), // Can this be done when I'm using NUMERIC and BETWEEN?
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### In the DB

In the databse my values are stored as strings i.e. **22mm**, **55mm** etc.

### Question

How can I tell the query to search a range and ignore the **mm** in **22mm**?

Comment: You couldn't store the units in a seperate meta value?

Comment: @Zogot Believe me I wanted to. But I couldn't at the time and now I have a lot of data which is not always the same :(

Comment: If your values are always "number" followed by "mm" then what you are doing should work. `CAST` will turn "55mm" into "55".

Comment: @s_ha_dum So, you're saying the code behind the scenes is converting the string into an int?

Comment: Yes. The query will `CAST` your value as `signed`-- `var_dump($the_query->request)`. Run `SELECT CAST("15mm" as signed)` in a MySQL console and you'll see that the letters are dropped leaving just "15" or whatever number you have in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercept the query on the `posts_where` filter. In there you can do a replacement of the non numeric values:

```
preg_replace( "/[^0-9,.]/", "", $yourMeta );
```

Or in a (generic) code piece:

```
add_action( 'posts_where', 'wpse120784WhereDiameter', 100 );
function wpse120784WhereDiameter( $where )
{
    // If conditions here - only target the cases where we need it
    # if ( foo ) { etc.

    // Only run once for this single query
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $diameter = get_post_meta( ... );
    $where .= preg_replace( "/[^0-9,.]/", $diameter, $where );

    return $where;
}
```

When you manage to target the exact MM diameters that you're searching for, then the Regex Search/Replace call will simply pop off the `MM`/`Inch` (whatever unit there is).

Of course you'll need to somehow gain access to the post meta (`get_post_meta()`) values to target them in the Regex replacement task more accurately, but it should bring you to your goal.

Still I think that removing the MM from your entries would be much easier and better than what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, but what? I'm not sure I understand how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: @hitautodestruct See update for an example. If this still isn't enough, then you'll find other examples for `posts_where` when searching the site.